# Why is "glRenderbufferStorageMultisample" giving error for following code?

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, fbo

Why is "*glRenderbufferStorageMultisample*" giving me an invalid operation error (1282)?

I'm trying to render a scene into a Multisampled FBO with color/depth **buffers only** (no textures here) & then resolve that Multisampled FBO into a simple FBO that has color/depth **textures**, but OpenGL just won't let me...

```
    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_Id);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_Id);

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &m_ColorId);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_ColorId);
    glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, numOfSamples, GL_RGBA8, width, height);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_ColorId);

    glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

The line that gives me error is "*glRenderbufferStorageMultisample*", interestingly enough though "*glRenderbufferStorage*" doesn't...

Comment: Can be: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glRenderbufferStorageMultisample.xhtml useful? I read that the value of numOfSamples, width, height it's relevant. What values are you using for those?

Comment: Hey, numOfSamples is 32, width is 720 and height is 480, no Idea why it's not letting me do it, I think I'm doing everything by the book... ogl version 3.3 as well

Comment: 32 seems to be a big number to me. About "samples specifies the number of samples to be used for the renderbuffer object's image, and must be less than or equal to the value of GL_MAX_SAMPLES", what's your GL_MAX_SAMPLE value? and what your video card is capable of?

Comment: Hey! Turns out it was indeed the number of samples being too high, thanks for the shoutout ;)

Comment: posted an answer, if you don't mind, please accept it. 'night, Ste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation at: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glRenderbufferStorageMultisample.xhtml, you should check the values of your parameters (used for the `glRenderbufferStorageMultisample` call against) some OpenGL macros.

Based on the details provided, a check on `numOfSamples` value (currently 32) it's my best suggestion. I believe it may be too high.

The maximum value for `numOfSamples` may be even limited by the capabilities of your video card.

Hope this may help,
Stefano